# Build Query object from query string - Objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

Is it possible to build a `Query` object with Objectify with a query string? I mean, I know Objectify builds queries like:

```
Query<Foo> q = ofy().load().type(Foo.class);
q = q.filter("bar", b);
```

However, is there a way or any plans for Objectify to have the ability to build Query objects from query string like:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE bar = b";
List<Foo> foo = ofy().buildQuery(query).asList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to build queries in Objectify from query string.